# Use of width in printf()

Tags: c++, c, printf

What is the use of width in the `printf()` statement? Why is the output 7 in the example below?

#### Code

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return printf("%*c%*c",  x, '\r',  y, '\r');
}

int main()
{
    printf("Sum = %d", add(3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

> Sum = 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` returns the number of characters output. `%*c` means print a character and pad to the width specified by an argument. So `printf("%*c", 3, '\r')` means to print a carriage return with 2 spaces before it. `printf("%*c%*c", n, '\r', m, '\r')` therefore prints `n` + `m` characters - that's `n` - 1 spaces to pad the first `\r`, `m` - 1 spaces to pad the second `\r`, and the two carriage returns. That's why it returns 7.

A carriage return takes you back to the start of the line, so after printing those `n` + `m` characters the next thing printed will appear at the start of the line. That means `"Sum = "` overwrites the output of the first printf.

Answer (score 4):

A) this is a totally crazy thing to do with printf.  But since you asked...

B) the `%*c` says to take the next two of printf's arguments, and interpret them as a width and a character.  Print that character in a field of the specified width.  In this case, print a field `x` wide containing the character `\r`.  Same for `y` and `\r`.  Printf returns the total number of characters printed, which in this case is `x+y`.

So the output is actually `x-1` spaces, an `\r` character, `y-1` spaces, another `\r` character (or are characters left-aligned?), followed by `Sum = 7`.

Answer (score 1):

If successful [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) returns the number of characters printed. So, your `printf`call in `main`  is printing the number of characters printed by the `printf` in the `add` function, because this is what `add` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Consulting any [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) shows that `printf` returns the number of characters that were printed, excluding the null terminator. `%*c` takes *two* arguments, the first being the field width (which is thus respectively 3 and 4), and the second being the actual character printed. In this case, the character is a carriage return (`\r`), which you probably can't see on your terminal. Since the two characters are printed with padding, a string of length 7 is printed, and 7 is returned.

Since you can't tell that spaces and carriage returns, it looks like nothing is printed at all -- try piping the output into a file or `hexdump`, though.

Comment: Precision would be `.*`, not just `*`. Field width is what is being specified here.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yes indeed, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

printf returns the number of characters printed. In this case you are printing 7 characters by specifying x and y as output lengths. If you change the return statement to:

```
return printf("%*c%*c\n",  x, '\r',  y, '\r');
```

The output will be 8, since a new line is also printed.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the name of your function is add, I highly doubt this is what you meant to do.

printf() returns the number of characters printed, which in this case is apparently 7 characters. You are then returning the value returned by printf() and printing it.

Seems like an odd thing to do. What were you expecting?

Comment: Anyone who downvotes an answer without explanation is a gutless lamo!

Comment: Sir, it is injustice if you did downvote me thinking I have downvoted you.